# Sharing data between master and reduce

Tags: mapreduce, elastic-map-reduce

I need to perform aggregation using the results form all the reduce tasks. Basically the reduce task finds the sum and count and a value. I need to add all the sums and counts and find the final average.

I tried using `conf.setInt` in reduce. But when I try to access it from the main function it fails

```
class Main {

public static class MyReducer 
extends Reducer<Text, Text,Text,IntWritable> {

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, 
            Context context
            ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int i = 0;
        int fd = 0, fc = 0;
        fd = context.getConfiguration().getInt("fd", -1);
        fc = context.getConfiguration().getInt("fc", -1);
        //when I check the value of fd, fc here they are fine. fc fd is shared across all reduce tasks and the updated value is seen by all reduce task. Only main function doesnt seem to have access to it.
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.setInt("fc", 5);

    Job job = new Job(conf, "Flight Data");
    job.setJarByClass(FlightData.class);
    job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(MyReducer.class);

    job.setPartitionerClass(FirstPartitioner.class);
    job.setGroupingComparatorClass(GroupComparator.class);
    job.setSortComparatorClass(KeyComparator.class);


    job.setNumReduceTasks(10);
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);


    flightCount = job.getConfiguration().getInt("fc", -1);
    flightDelay = job.getConfiguration().getInt("fd", -1);
    //here when I access fc, fd, I get back 5 & 5
    System.out.println("Final " + flightCount +" " + flightDelay+ " " + flightDelay/flightCount);
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Also can you add the language you are using as a tag?

Answer (score 0):

Override the `run()` of the mapper and reducer using the new `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce` API. In these methods you can emit the accumulated sum/count from each mapper or reducer.

Also you would need to limit the reducer count by 1 so as to get a global sum of all the sums generated by multiple mappers.

See the below code for more clarity:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;

public class AggregationExample extends Configured implements Tool {

    /**
     * This is Mapper.
     * 
     */
    public static class MapJob extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

        private Text outputKey = new Text();
        private Text outputValue = new Text();
        private double sum;

        @Override
        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            try {
                // say that you need to sum up the value part
                sum+= Double.valueOf(value);
        }

        @Override
        public void run(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            setup(context);
            while (context.nextKeyValue()) {
                map(context.getCurrentKey(), context.getCurrentValue(), context);
            }

            // emit out the sum per mapper
            outputKey.set(sum);
            context.write(outputKey, outputValue);// Notice that the outputValue is empty
            cleanup(context);

        }
    }

    /**
     * This is Reducer.
     * 
     */
    public static class ReduceJob extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

        private Text outputKey = new Text();
        private Text outputValue = new Text();
        private double sum;

        @Override
        protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException,
                InterruptedException {


            // summation of values from each mapper
            sum += Double.valueOf(key.toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void run(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            setup(context);
            while (context.nextKey()) {
                reduce(context.getCurrentKey(), context.getValues(), context);
            }

            // emit out the global sums
            outputKey.set(sum);
            context.write(outputKey, outputValue);
            cleanup(context);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {

        try {
            Configuration conf = getConf();

            // output key and value separator is empty as in final output only
            // key is emitted and value is empty
            conf.set("mapred.textoutputformat.separator", "");

            // Configuring mapred to have just one reducer as we need to find
            // single sum values from all the inputs
            conf.setInt("mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum", 1);
            conf.setInt("mapred.reduce.tasks", 1);

            Job job = new Job(conf);

            job.setJarByClass(AggregationExample.class);
            job.setJobName("Aggregation Example");

            job.setMapperClass(MapJob.class);
            job.setReducerClass(ReduceJob.class);
            job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
            job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

            job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
            job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
            job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
            job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
            FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, args[0]);
            FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

            boolean success = job.waitForCompletion(true);
            return success ? 0 : 1;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return 1;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        if (args.length < 2) {
            System.out
                    .println("Usage: AggregationExample <comma sparated list of input directories> <output dir>");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        int result = ToolRunner.run(new AggregationExample(), args);
        System.exit(result);
    }

}
```

You may very well map this approach to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. I used counters

http://diveintodata.org/2011/03/15/an-example-of-hadoop-mapreduce-counter/

public class FlightData {

```
//enum for counters used by reducers
public static enum FlightCounters {
    FLIGHT_COUNT,
    FLIGHT_DELAY;
}
public static class MyReducer 
extends Reducer<Text, Text,Text,IntWritable> {

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, 
            Context context
            ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {


        delay1 = Float.parseFloat(origin[5]);
        delay2 = Float.parseFloat(dest[5]);
        context.getCounter(FlightCounters.FLIGHT_COUNT).increment(1);
        context.getCounter(FlightCounters.FLIGHT_DELAY)
        .increment((long) (delay1 + delay2));

    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    float flightCount, flightDelay;
    job.waitForCompletion(true);
    //get the final results updated in counter by all map and reduce tasks
    flightCount = job.getCounters()
            .findCounter(FlightCounters.FLIGHT_COUNT).getValue();
    flightDelay = job.getCounters()
            .findCounter(FlightCounters.FLIGHT_DELAY).getValue();
}
```

}